UEFI Application: UEFI NTFS driver is not loading properly
I'm working on an EFI application to load an NTFS driver (ntfs_x64.efi). When I load the driver from the EFI shell using "load ntfs_x64.efi" command, it works perfectly. However, when I try to load the driver programmatically from within my EFI application, it loads, but Type and #D are not getting assigned.
DRV | Version | Type | CFG | DIAG | #D | #C | DriverName | ImageName |
Working (Shell)
enter image description here
Not Working (EFI APP)
enter image description here
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue.
Program
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
LoadNtfsDriver(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status;
    EFI_HANDLE LoadedImageHandle;
    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL *LoadedImage;
    EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *DevicePath;
    UINTN ExitDataSize = 4*1024;
    CHAR16 *ExitData = NULL;

    // Allocate memory for ExitData
    ExitData = AllocatePool(ExitDataSize);
    if (ExitData == NULL) {
        Print(L"Failed to allocate memory for ExitData.\n");
        return EFI_OUT_OF_RESOURCES;
    }
    Print(L"Memory allocated\n");

    // Get the Loaded Image Protocol for the current image to access its device handle
    Status = gBS->OpenProtocol(
        ImageHandle,
        &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid,
        (VOID **)&LoadedImage,
        ImageHandle,
        NULL,
        EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_GET_PROTOCOL);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to get LoadedImageProtocol: %r\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    // Create a device path for the NTFS driver file
    DevicePath = FileDevicePath(LoadedImage->DeviceHandle, NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
    if (DevicePath == NULL)
    {
        Print(L"Failed to create device path for %s\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
        return EFI_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Load the NTFS driver (ntfs_x64.efi)
    Status = gBS->LoadImage(
        FALSE,             // Not a Boot Image
        ImageHandle,       // Parent image handle
        DevicePath,        // Path to the NTFS driver
        NULL,              // Optional source buffer
        0,                 // Size of the source buffer
        &LoadedImageHandle // Image handle for the loaded driver
    );
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to load %s: %r\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH, Status);
        FreePool(DevicePath);
        return Status;
    }
    Print(L"%s loaded successfully.\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
    Print(L"Status: %r\n", Status);
    
    // Start the NTFS driver
    Status = gBS->StartImage(
        LoadedImageHandle,
        &ExitDataSize, // Optional exit data size
        &ExitData  // Optional exit data
    );
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to start %s: %r\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH, Status);
    }
    else
    {
        Print(L"%s started successfully.\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
        Print(L"Status: %r\n", Status);
        Print(L"Exit Data: %s\n", ExitData);
    }

    // Free allocated device path memory
    FreePool(DevicePath);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}


Do you connect the driver in a later step?

How can I connect the driver? I tried using ConnectController method but the call was not successful. Maybe I'm missing something. Can you check?
Status = gBS->ConnectController(ImageHandle, NULL, NULL, TRUE);


I connected the driver to all the handles of Disk IO protocols and the issue resolved.
EFI_STATUS
EFIAPI
LoadNtfsDriver(EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE *SystemTable)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status;
    EFI_HANDLE LoadedImageHandle;
    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL *LoadedImage;
    EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL *DevicePath;
    UINTN ExitDataSize = 4*1024;
    CHAR16 *ExitData = NULL;

    Status = gBS->OpenProtocol(
        ImageHandle,
        &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid,
        (VOID **)&LoadedImage,
        ImageHandle,
        NULL,
        EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_GET_PROTOCOL);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to get LoadedImageProtocol: %r\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    DevicePath = FileDevicePath(LoadedImage->DeviceHandle, NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
    if (DevicePath == NULL)
    {
        Print(L"Failed to create device path for %s\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
        return EFI_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    Status = gBS->LoadImage(
        FALSE,             // Not a Boot Image
        ImageHandle,       // Parent image handle
        DevicePath,        // Path to the NTFS driver
        NULL,              // Optional source buffer
        0,                 // Size of the source buffer
        &LoadedImageHandle // Image handle for the loaded driver
    );
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to load %s: %r\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH, Status);
        FreePool(DevicePath);
        return Status;
    }
    Print(L"%s loaded successfully.\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
    Print(L"Status: %r\n", Status);
    
    // Start the NTFS driver
    Status = gBS->StartImage(
        LoadedImageHandle,
        &ExitDataSize, // Optional exit data size
        &ExitData  // Optional exit data
    );
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        Print(L"Failed to start %s: %r\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH, Status);
    }
    else
    {
        Print(L"%s started successfully.\n", NTFS_DRIVER_PATH);
        Print(L"Status: %r\n", Status);
        Print(L"Exit Data: %s\n", ExitData);
    }
    
    EFI_HANDLE *HandleBuffer;
    UINTN HandleCount;
    UINTN Index;

    // Locate all handles supporting the Disk I/O protocol
    Status = gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(
        ByProtocol,
        &gEfiDiskIoProtocolGuid,
        NULL,
        &HandleCount,
        &HandleBuffer);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(L"Failed to locate Disk IO handles: %r\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    for (Index = 0; Index < HandleCount; Index++) {
        // Attempt to connect the controller for each handle
        Status = gBS->ConnectController(
            HandleBuffer[Index],
            NULL,
            NULL,
            TRUE);
        if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
            Print(L"Failed to connect controller for handle %d: %r\n", Index, Status);
        } else {
            Print(L"Controller connected for handle %d.\n", Index);
        }
    }

    if (HandleBuffer) {
        FreePool(HandleBuffer);
    }

    // Free allocated device path memory
    FreePool(DevicePath);

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}

